# Angular 6 - issue with nested routes

Tags: angular6, angular-routing

I'm trying to setup up nested routes for an `admin` parent menu. Below admin I have two child routes - `Security Settings` and `Configuration`.

When I click on the `Configuration` menu item, my page is redirected to `AdminComponent` and renders `Admin works`. However, if I click on `Site Configuration`, it does NOT redirect to my `SiteConfigComponent` as I expect it to; it just redirects to `AdminComponent` again.

i.e. Here's the `siteconfig` route snippet which is also shown again below.

```
 <a mat-button routerLink="/admin/siteconfig">
        Site Configuration
    </a>
```

HTML:

```html
<a mat-button routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="horizontal-active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">Home</a>

<a mat-button routerLink="/preferences" routerLinkActive="horizontal-active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">Preferences</a>

<a mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">Admin
<mat-icon class="caret">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
</a>

<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" class="mega-menu app-dropdown">
<div fxLayout="column wrap">
 <div fxFlex class="p-1">
  <a mat-menu-item routerLink="/admin" routerLinkActive="horizontal-active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
   <b>Configuration</b>
  </a>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  <button mat-menu-item>Security Settings</button>            
  <a mat-button routerLink="/admin/siteconfig" routerLinkActive="horizontal-active-link">
   Site Configuration
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
</mat-menu>
```

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: '', 
        component: PagesComponent, children: [
            { path: '', component:HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
            { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent,
              children: [
                { path: '', component: AdminComponent },
                { path: 'management/users', component: UsersManagementComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
                { path: 'management/roles', component: RolesManagementComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
                { path: 'siteconfig', component: SiteConfigComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
              ], 
                canLoad: [AuthGuard]
            }
        ]
    },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},       
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

And app.component.html (loaded by index.html) is :

```
<div id="app" class="100h app" [ngClass]="appSession.settings.Theme"> 
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Again, if I click on `Site Config` it should go to the `SiteConfigComonent`.

Advice appreciated...

Comment: getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No I'm not. But whether I navigate to `http://localhost:4200/admin` or `http://localhost:4200/admin/siteconfig`, I'm still seeing the text "admin works". My main top nav menu is still there as well, but if I attempt to go straight to `http://localhost:4200/siteconfig` - of course my top nav is gone.